# I have a form with input as images and I can not figure out how to send the name attribute of the input tag to mysql database?

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql

So I want the user to select one of the images from a form displayed but I do not want to upload an image, just send the name of that image to my database.

I saw a couple of solutions about uploading images to the database, but I can not figure out how to just send the name of the image selected by the user

The end result would be basically the information sent to mysql database.

```html
<p class="questions">What type of roof do you have?</p>
<div id="roof-type">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <form method="post" action="action.php">
        <input type="image" src="images/asphalt.png" name="asphalt" id="asphalt" />
        <input type="image" src="images/metal.png" name="metal" id="metal" />
        <input type="image" src="images/flat.png" name="flat" id="flat" />
        <input type="image" src="images/clay.png" name="clay" id="clay" />
        <input type="image" src="images/cement.png" name="cement" id="cement" />
        <input type="image" src="images/other.png" name="other-roof" id="other-roof" />
        <input type='hidden' name='roof_type' /> 

      </form>
    </tr>


    </table>
</div>
  



<script>
  let input = document.querySelector('input[type="hidden"][name="roof_type"]');
let col = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="image"]');
Array.prototype.slice.call(col).forEach(img => {
    img.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      input.value = this.name;
      input.parentNode.submit();
    })
  })

  </script>
```

```html
<?php
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}


$roof_type = $_POST['roof_type'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO testing_database ". "(roof_type) ". "VALUES($roof_type)";

mysql_select_db('test');
        $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

        if(! $retval ) {
           die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
        }

        echo "Entered data successfully\n";

?>
```

I was trying to check if I see any output if I echo roof_type, but I don't see anything at the moment, and these are the following errors I am getting:

- Notice: Undefined variable: link in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\action.php 
  Notice: Undefined index: roof_type in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\action.php
  Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be
  mysqli, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\action.php

Comment: What does your current `PHP` look like to get the form data?

Comment: $roof_type = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['roof_type']);
echo($roof_type);

I was trying the above to see if I am getting any response, but it doesn't display anything.  I get these following errors, if I click on an image:

Notice: Undefined variable: link in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\action.php on line 15

Notice: Undefined index: roof_type in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\action.php on line 15

Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\action.php on line 15

Comment: Please update your question and include the source code there rather than trying to share it via the comments section. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, I see this question also has a javascript tag to it. Can you use jQuery?

Comment: I do not have much experience with jQuery, but if you think it will help me, I will surely look into it.

Comment: your HTML is invalid. You cannot have the FORM there like it is - it must either be wholly contained within a table cell `<td>` or the entire table must be within the form. The same thing applies to the other HTML elements that you have there.... they are invalid in this context

Comment: Thanks everyone! I used all three answers to get what I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per comment above, the HTML in the question was not valid so I made appropriate changes below to correct that. The code below uses a hidden field which is populated when an image is clicked by means of some simple javascript. Once the hidden input has been assigned the `name` attribute from the image the form is submitted - thus in your PHP you should now be able to access `$_POST['roof_type']`

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <p class="questions">What type of roof do you have?</p>
            <div id="roof-type">
                <form method="post" action="action.php">
                    <input type="image" src="images/asphalt.png" name="asphalt" id="asphalt" />
                    <input type="image" src="images/metal.png" name="metal" id="metal" />
                    <input type="image" src="images/flat.png" name="flat" id="flat" />
                    <input type="image" src="images/clay.png" name="clay" id="clay" />
                    <input type="image" src="images/cement.png" name="cement" id="cement" />
                    <input type="image" src="images/other.png" name="other-roof" id="other-roof" />
                    <input type='hidden' name='roof_type' />
                </form>

                <script>
                    let input=document.querySelector( 'input[type="hidden"][name="roof_type"]' );
                    let col=document.querySelectorAll( 'input[type="image"]' );
                    Array.prototype.slice.call( col ).forEach( img =>{
                        img.addEventListener('click', function(e){
                            e.preventDefault();
                            input.value=this.name;
                            input.parentNode.submit();
                        })
                    })

                </script>

            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The error relating to `undefined variable "link"` is caused by the misuse of a variable $link in the call to `mysqli_real_escape_string` - it should instead use `$conn` like this:

```
$roof_type = isset( $_POST['roof_type'] ) ? mysqli_real_escape_string( $conn, $_POST['roof_type'] ) : false;
if( $roof_type ) echo $roof_type;
else echo "error....";
```

The PHP code to handle the request had some issues - most notably the mixing of apis and the SQL injection vulnerability. Perhaps the following might help in that respect.

```
<?php

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if ($conn->connect_error) die("Connection failed");

    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && isset( $_POST['roof_type'] ) ){
        $roof_type = $_POST['roof_type'];
        $sql='insert into `testing_database` set `roof_type`=?';
        $stmt=$conn->prepare($sql);

        if( $stmt ){
            $stmt->bind_param( 's', $roof_type );
            $res=$stmt->execute();
            $message = $res ? 'Entered data successfully' : 'Could not enter data';

            die( $message );            
        } else {
            exit('bad foo');
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: I tried this with input type hidden as you showed here, but I still do not get the value passed into the database.

Comment: please add the code you use to try to add this information to the database with

Comment: The `mySQL` api was deprecated a long time ago and has been removed from PHP after v7. What version of PHP do you have? It is, by the way, insecure anyway - sql injection is possible. You appear to mix api - `mysql` and `mysqli`

Comment: I have version 10 of php, I am using xampp i don't know if that makes any difference

Comment: Thank you very much, I did change it into radio button but your suggestions were very very help[ful

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use radio buttons. Simply create the images in the table, then underneath each image have a radio button to select that particular image.

Right now, by setting your input type to image, your POST request is expecting image data, not a selection.

Here's a [link](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_radio.asp) to radio buttons for reference.

Comment: Yeah that what I was thinking too but I wanted to confirm it before I go down that way.  Thanks for the suggestion though

Answer (score 0):

Since you stated jQuery is an option for you... You can do this without a form. Example

```
<img src="images/flat.png" id="flat" class="imgSelect">
```

Then in jQuery

```
$('.imgSelect').click(function(){
  var imgId = $(this).attr('id');
  $.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "databaseProcess.php",
  data: { imgId: imgId }
});
```

You could also add an "onclick" event to each image

```
<img src="images/flat.png" id="flat" onclick="doFunction()" />
```

Comment: So you saying if I need to change the class attribute to imgSelect for all the input type images and then just write the jQuery inside the script tags ?

Comment: Pretty much. It would save you a lot of programming and hassle with the form.